# SharpDevelop does not show variable values in debug when hovering

Tags: c#, debugging, variables, sharpdevelop

I have SharpDevelop 4.1 and 4.4. When I compile an application and debug it, I cannot see variable values when hovering over them. I presume it must be some configuration issue because I have the same 4.4 installed on another machine where this feature works. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: are you using a single or dual monitor..also do you have any virus scan currently running this hapens to me from time to time even with vs2012 IDE and I have to minimize the screen then maximize or move it over to the second monitor hover over it to check if it's working then move the ide back to my main monitor.. I've seriously found this issue a lot when the `SEP` daily virus scan for our Semantic is running ..it's a pain in the butt sometimes

Comment: no virus scan at all. one monitor only

Answer (score 0):

This post is old but can help developers with this kind of behavior.
I had the same issue with SharpDevelop 5.1.

The solution is:

1. Go to "Build" menu.
2. Choose "Set configuration".
3. Be sure your are in "Debug" mode and not in Release one.

That's all. Hope it helps.